# How to Reload a fragment after the share intent?

Tags: android

I have three fragments and in one of the fragments, i have many imageViews which are loaded by different images. I have a share button, which is used to share the combination of all imageviews using Canvas. The share function works perfectly for the first load. When we click the share button again, the app crashes.

I would like to reload the fragment, when the share is completed /cancelled.

Is there any way to do this ?

This is how the fragments are loaded

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three,container,false);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three,container,false);
    return view;
}

public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        final View v = rootView;
        final Context context = null;
...................

}
```

Sorry, no space to accommodate all the codes

Here is the code used to share inside the view

```
    img = (ImageView)getView(). findViewById(R.id.imageView15);

    collageImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewcam);
        collageImage.destroyDrawingCache();
        collageImage.buildDrawingCache();
        collageImage.getDrawingCache();
        collageImage.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

       mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(450,350, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBackgroundImage);


img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView img1 = null;

                img1 = (ImageView)getView(). findViewById(R.id.imageViewcam);
                img1.destroyDrawingCache();
                img1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                img1.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap1=null;
                bmap1 = img1.getDrawingCache();


           ImageView img3 = (ImageView)getView(). findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
               img3.destroyDrawingCache();
               img3.buildDrawingCache();
               Bitmap bmap3 = img3.getDrawingCache();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap1);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmap1, 0f, 0f, null);

        float xo51 = img3.getX(); // x-coordinate
                float yo51 = img3.getY();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmap3, xo51, yo51, null);

        collageImage.setImageBitmap(bmap1);
                Drawable mDrawable = collageImage.getDrawable();

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                {
                    if (checkPermission())
                    {

                        try {
                            File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(),"logicchip.png");
                            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();
                            file.setReadable(true, false);
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                            intent.setType("image/png");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        requestPermission(); // Code for permission
                    }
                }
                else
                {


                }

        }
        });
    }
```

What im looking for is either to avoid share error

Error : Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap in android

*And its happening in img1.buildDrawingCache();*

or reload the entire fragment.

The third fragment is reloaded when we activate fragment1.

Hope its clear..

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

`//for reload fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hundler,Main_Fragment()).commit();`

Comment: Thanks, but crashing.. im combining all the imageview as a bitmap and is used for sharing. Its works only one time. When we share second time, app crashes. So i need to reload the fragment once the intent has been completed to avoid the second share...any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this for fragment calling..

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to use this when the share intent is completed. Is there any way to detect that ?. I tried your code, but syntax error and replaced with  "getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main,getTargetFragment()).commit();"  After the share intent. App crashing.. but share window stays there....